# Swift Using NSFetchedResultsController to update TableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, core-data

I have an `NSFetchedResultsController` that is populating a `TableView`. The `TableView` is using custom cells.

When I search I am getting the correct results but the TableView isn't getting updated, any ideas?

```
func controller(
    controller: NSFetchedResultsController,
    didChangeObject anObject: AnyObject,
    atIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath?,
    forChangeType type: NSFetchedResultsChangeType,
    newIndexPath: NSIndexPath?) {

        switch type {
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeType.Insert:
            if let insertIndexPath = newIndexPath {
                self.tblJobs.insertRowsAtIndexPaths([insertIndexPath], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Fade)
            }
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeType.Delete:
            if let deleteIndexPath = indexPath {
                self.tblJobs.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([deleteIndexPath], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Fade)
            }
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeType.Update:
            // Note that for Update, we update the row at __indexPath__
            if let updateIndexPath = indexPath {
                let cell =  self.tblJobs.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(
                    "JobCell")
                    as! JobTableViewCell
                //let cell = self.tblJobs.cellForRowAtIndexPath(updateIndexPath)
                let workItem = self.fetchedResultsController.objectAtIndexPath(updateIndexPath) as? Work

            }
```

And heres my search function:

```
func searchBar(searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
        println("Search text is \(searchText)")
      savedSearchTerm = searchText


        if(savedSearchTerm!.length == 0){
            searchActive = false;
        } else {
            searchActive = true;


             self.fetchedResultsController.fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format:"town CONTAINS[cd] %@", savedSearchTerm!)

            var error: NSError? = nil
            self.fetchedResultsController.performFetch(&error)
            if (error != nil) {
                NSLog("Unable to perform fetch.")
                NSLog("%@, %@", error!, error!.localizedDescription)
            }else{

               var  filteredWorkItems = self.fetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects

                println("fetched objects are: \(filteredWorkItems)")

            }
             self.tblJobs.reloadData()
        }


    }
```

Update, cellForRowAtIndexPath function

```
 func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell{
    println("getting hit")

    let cell =  self.tblJobs.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(
        "JobCell")
        as! JobTableViewCell

    let workItem = fetchedResultsController.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! Work

    var parties: NSSet = workItem.parties

    var arr = parties.allObjects //Swift Array

    var party = arr.first as! Party

    var partyName = "\(party.title.desc) \(party.firstName) \(party.lastName)"




    cell.lblAddress?.text = "\(workItem.propertyNumber) \(workItem.street) \(workItem.town) \(workItem.locality) \(workItem.postcode)"

    cell.lblSchemeType?.text = workItem.scheme.desc

    let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd/MM/YY"



    let dateString = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(workItem.createdDate)

    cell.lblCreatedDate?.text = dateString
    cell.lblPartyDetails?.text = partyName



    return cell
}
```

Comment: When you say you're getting the correct results, do you mean your fetched results controller has the objects you expect it to have?

Comment: yes, when i println the fetchedObjects, they are correct, they just wont show in the table. Well, the section title shows but none of my custom cell fields are :S)

Comment: What does your cellForRowAtIndexPath method look like? And is it getting hit?

Comment: i'eve updated my question with that function, it doesn't get hit every time I enter a character into the search bar no

Comment: It gets hit sometimes or never?

Comment: it gets hit when the view is loaded, and it gets hit when i press the search bar, but after that no

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87400/discussion-between-fr0s1yjack-and-mikeatnobel).

Comment: I think the problem is the tableview that the UISearchDelegate is using is obstructing my actual table, when I end the search and call reloadData() on the table it shows up :S

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately this was a blunder on my part, the reason I was able to view the section title but no actual rows were being displayed was because I had left a silly boolean check in my `numberOfRowsInSection` function from a previous attempt at getting this to work:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int{
    // return workItems.count
    if searchActive{
    return filteredWorkItems.count
    }
    if let sections = fetchedResultsController.sections {
        let currentSection = sections[section] as! NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo
        return currentSection.numberOfObjects
    }

    return 0

}
```

I removed that `if searchActive` block and the info magically displayed, as the `FRC` and `TableView` were already doing what they were supposed to

Answer (score 0):

You can use the same table for searching and for displaying. You need to disable the superimposed table view (the `UISearchController` interface).

You need to **not** use a `UISearchController`, just the `UISearchBar`. Use its `UISearchBarDelegate` methods to trigger updates of the *original* table.